# Why are infinitive complements analysed as separate clauses?

Tags: syntax, english, clauses, infinitive

Why is the sentence

> John wants to read.

normally analysed as consisting of 2 clauses? (John wants, PRO to read)

I understand the idea of PRO but why must *to read* be a completely different clause?

What does the traditional syntax say about such examples? Does it also claim that there are 2 clauses?

But the sentence

> John wants a book.

is only analysed as 1 clause. (Or am I mistaken?)

Why is there a difference?

Comment: This has always bugged me too. Either I never fully grokked it or other analyses may be possible that some of us might find more intuitive ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends who you talk to, but I think there's some logic in saying that a clause is simply another name for a verb phrase. (Ignoring non-verbal clauses.) Two verbs mean two clauses.

Infinitive arguments can have their own set of independent arguments and adjuncts. Here is a complex example, but I think it illustrates that there are two clauses quite clearly:

> *Last night* *at the bus stop* **the son** `wished` for **the father** `to read` **a story** to **him** *in bed* *when they next went to grandma's house*.

Two locative adjuncts: *at the bus stop* and *in bed*
Two temporal adjuncts: *Last night* and *when they next went to grandma's house*
Two subject arguments: **the son** and **the father** 
And the infinitive verb has its own set of object arguments which are not arguments of *wish*: **a story** and **him**

Strip all that back and you get

> The son wished to read.

Rather than propose that it has a different structure I think it's best to say that it has the same structure: two clauses.

Comment: Downvote: The second sentence is definitely **not** what the first one is about. The first one shows a desiderative construction, where the son wants somebody else (=his father) to read something. The second sentence shows a volitive construction: the son wants/wishes to do something himself. In volitive constructions, the subject argument of the volition equals the subject argument of the activity, in desideratives, subject arguments are distinct.

Comment: @ThomasGross I wasn't implying the sentences were equivalent and I don't know why you'd think I was. I know the subject of the infinitive changes.

Answer (score 0):

Clauses are usually made up of **finite verbs** in predicates and additional dependent information. "John wants to read" and "John wants a book" are more-less equivalent. Non-finite verbs, such as "to read" (a full infinitive) are usually parts of a **verb chain/verb catena**. The difference between those two is just that there is a noun in the second sentence and a non-finite verb in the first. Both are **mono-clausal**. You might've gotten the bi-clausal bit of data from some book; it is probably mistaken (at least as far as I know). It might have a different definition of clause.

Comment: If you're couching your answer within a particular framework (in this case dependency gramar), do make it explicit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using dependency grammar mostly here. EDIT: Just saw you mentioned it's dependency; double facepalm insues

Comment: No worries, I just think it's good practice. Just to satisfy my own curiosity, how to non-finite interrogative clauses fit into this picture (Dependency Grammar)? Are they mono- or bi-clausal? "John knows where to go".

Comment: The thing that goes here is that those bits of verb chains are nonfinite clauses/"defective" clauses (as I've somewhere read). That's a relative nonfinite clause introduced by an interrogative pronoun; I'd probably not go wrong to say it's bi-clausal. It differs from "wants to X" in that it's made up of a full nonfinite clause while "to X" is bare. In general, non-finite verbs are limited as to what kinds of clauses they can form.

Answer (score 0):

This is the analysis of generative grammar, there is a D-structure for a sentence, which is usually much different from the S-structure of the sentence. By D-structure, you can know why, to understand D-structure, you have to know a lot of reasons or evidences that support those structures.So, it seemingly is not consistent with traditional analysis.see Chomskyan works for reference. BTW, I don't think clause is an important notion of generative grammar.

Comment: Why did you make a second answer? This is essentially the same as your first one. You should have just edited it.

Comment: @curiousdannii about the flag... mods can't merge posts. It's up to the original authors to make all such modifications.